# Misunderstanding of an exercise in Görtz-Wedhorn: When do the nilradical and Jacobson radical coincide?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Exercise 2.3 of Görtz-Wedhorn, *Algebraic Geometry I*, states that

> *the nilradical of $A$ is equal to the Jacobson of $A$ if and only if every non-empty open subset of $\operatorname{Spec}A$ contains a closed point.*

My issue is as follows: if every non-empty open subset of $\operatorname{Spec}A$ contains a closed point, in particular for every $f \neq 0$ the open subset $D(f)$ contains a closed point, i.e. a maximal ideal $\mathfrak{m}$. In other words, there is a maximal ideal that does *not* contain $f$, so in particular $f \notin J(A)$, where $J(A)$ is Jacobson of $A$. This means that $J(A) = \{0\}$, so that the nilradical and Jacobson coincide because they are both zero.
This seems false, though - there seem to be rings $A$ for which the nilradical and the Jacobson coincide, but they are non-zero (for example, $\mathbb{Q}[x]/(x^2))$.

Comment: I am not sure how you get $J(A)=0$ here. For $f\in J(A)$ such that  $D(f)$ is non empty, then by assumption we have a maximal ideal $\mathfrak{m}$ not containing $f$, contradicting $f\in J(A)$. So $D(f) = \emptyset$. So $f$ lies in the nilradical of $A$.

Comment: If $f$ is any non-zero element, then $D(f)$ contains a maximal ideal, hence there exists a maximal ideal that does not contain $f$. As a consequence, $f$ is not in $J(A)$, so for every $f \neq 0$, $f \notin J(A)$. Hence $J(A) = 0$. This was my line of thought, but I guess the issue is that $D(f)$ needn't be non-empty?

Comment: This is a terrifying thought, but reasonable. Thanks!

Comment: You’re welcome!

Comment: A small formatting tip: `\operatorname{Spec}` produces better formatting for $\operatorname{Spec}$, and I've made the upgrade for you in your post this time. Unrelatedly, $D(f)$ is empty iff $f$ is nilpotent, which shouldn't be so surprising - you already know $D(0)$ is empty, no?

Answer (score 2):

You want to prove that $J(A)$ is contained in the nilradical $N(A)$ (the other inclusion being true over any commutative ring).

Suppose $f\notin N(A)$. Then there exists a prime ideal $\mathfrak{p}$ such that $f\notin\mathfrak{p}$. Then $D(f)\ne\emptyset$, so there exists a closed point in $D(f)$, that is, a maximal ideal $\mathfrak{m}$ such that $f\notin\mathfrak{m}$; therefore $f\notin J(A)$.